# Configuring Grunt Task in the Release Pipeline

Tags: gruntjs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have added a Grunt task to my release pipeline.  When the Grunt task runs, I get the following error:

> `Grunt-cli is not installed globally (or is not in the path of the user the agent is running as) and it is not in the local working folder:`
>
> `C:\agent\_work\r9\a\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt`

Any idea how to correct this error?

Comment: Did you add a npm install task before Grunt task? And can you should the whole build logs here?

Answer (score 0):

To ascertain whether [grunt-cli](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli) is installed globally on your system run the following command via your CLI :

`npm list -g grunt-cli`

If it reports `(empty)` then install `grunt-cli` globally by running:

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: I'm still getting the error after installing it as the service account on the build agent.

Comment: It shows to be empty.  So I run npm install -g grunt-cli.  Shows updated 1 package.  Then I run npm list -g grunt-cli and it shows to be empty again.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue with our build pipeline on a (self-hosted) Agent...

I tried to install grunt-cli locally but it didn't work-out also.

After running the command `npm list -g` in script task, in yaml: `- script: npm list -g`, i found-out that the agent has another global folder, which should look like this (depending which user runs the `azure pipelines agent` service, for me was (`local-system`):

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

So, i configured the `grunt-task` to search for the grunt-cli in the `node_modules` in that location. In `yaml` pipeline plan it looks like this:

```
# Need to run at the first build, then set enabled to false
- task: Npm@1
  enabled: false
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'install -g grunt-cli'

- task: Grunt@0
  displayName: Run Grunt tasks
  inputs:
    gruntFile: Gruntfile.js
    gruntCli: 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt'
```

I had to run the `npm i -g grunt-cli` in my pipeline to get grunt-cli installed globally for the agent.

Hopping that would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this issue, the option I took is within the Grunt task either:

1. set the Working Directory on the Grunt task to the relative path of your gruntfile.js

or

2. prepend the relative path above to the source in the grunt-cli location and leave the working directory blank.

Note, this assumes you have the grunt-cli listed as a dependency in your package.json.